# HSQLDB - which is the main database file

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB in the embedded mode.

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:abc\\TESTDB;
```

After creating the database, the folder `abc` has the following files:

```
TESTDB.lck TESTDB.script TESTDB.log TESTDB.properties
```

My application is working properly

But my question is which is the main database file amongst the above-listed files?

Or is the main database file stored in some other location?

Answer (score 11):

***.script*** contains all the statements to create the tables, alter them and insert the data. This file is created when you use hsqldb in memory. (so I'd say this is your database)
Otherwise the database is stored in ***.data*** as other people already said

***.lck*** is the lock file by which hsqldb knows whether the database is locked by a process. Usually you have this file only while your program is running and it is automatically deleted when you stop the programm.

***.log*** contains internal log statements of running transactions for example and some commit or rollback points.

***.properties*** contains the properties with which hsqldb is initialized (better don't change anything there if you don't know what you are doing). This is not to be confused with and persistence unit configuration.

kind regards

Comment: thanks peshkira. Since the tables created resides in MEMORY i think the only script file is the DB file and there is no .data file(since i am not using CACHED tables)

Comment: In case anyone lands here and is looking for a way to get the `.data` file created (ie: to get new tables created as `CACHED`; one simply needs to add `;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached` to the `jdbc.url` connection string.

Comment: ...further it may also help to specify `;shutdown=true` to the URL.

Answer (score 9):

A file containing your actual data might not exist in your folder for various reasons - particularly if you are using in-memory or non-cached tables. HSQLDB uses the various files you found in its working folder for a variety of reasons. You can read more about their purpose here: [HSQLDB Reference](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html).

I paraphrase some of the more relevant information:

> The script file contains the
>   definition of tables and other
>   database objects, plus the data for
>   non-cached tables. The log file
>   contains recent changes to the
>   database. The data file contains the
>   data for cached tables and the backup
>   file is a zipped backup of the last
>   known consistent state of the data
>   file. All these files are essential
>   and should never be deleted. If the
>   database has no cached tables, the
>   test.data and test.backup files will
>   not be present. In addition to those
>   files, HSQLDB database may link to any
>   formatted text files, such as CSV
>   lists, anywhere on the disk.
>
> While the "test" database is
>   operational, a test.log file is used
>   to write the changes made to data.
>   This file is removed at a normal
>   SHUTDOWN. Otherwise (with abnormal
>   shutdown) this file is used at the
>   next startup to redo the changes. A
>   test.lck file is also used to record
>   the fact that the database is open.
>   This is deleted at a normal SHUTDOWN.
>   In some circumstances, a test.data.old
>   is created and deleted afterwards.

Comment: Please correct. There is no testdb.data file because he has only the default MEMORY tables and no CACHED tables. Together, all his files make up the database.

Comment: I was pointing him to the file that would contain actual data, as indicated in his question. However I edited my answer to make it more clear what the various files in HSQLDB are for.

Comment: +1 for improvement. His data is in script and log files and will not go into the data file because he has only memory tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a `.data` file after adding records to database. In the case I'm wrong here are the documentation for you:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apc.html

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html