# HSQLDB Properties in Java

Tags: java, hsqldb

can someone tell me why the parameters that i'm inserting in the url connecting to the bank are not changing?
for example: the `hsqldb.full_log_replay = true` property in the database remains false, I have already tried to recreate the bank and still have not changed

```java
connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/db;ifexists=false;" +
    "shutdown=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false;hsqldb.write_delay=false;hsqldb.full_log_replay=true",
    "SA", "", new HsqldbDatabaseType());
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/db;ifexists=false;" +
    "shutdown=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false;hsqldb.write_delay=false;hsqldb.full_log_replay=true");
```

Comment: Did you try using `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` that accepts `Properties` instance as a  separate parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The properties `ifexists` and `shutdown` are properties for an individual connection. But the property `hsqlb.lock_file` is a database operation property and the properties `hsqldb.write_delay` + `hsqldb.full_log_replay` are database file and memory properties. So these properties are not changed when you try to connect in the Java code. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html).

If you still want to change the properties, you can create a `db.properties` file for your database. This file contains the properties for the database itself. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471969/hsqldb-which-is-the-main-database-file) describes other files that are created for the database.

Comment: my database has a db.properties file, however when I put `hsqldb.full_log_replay` it changes the value in the database, but whenever I restart the database it removes the ownership of the database and changes the value back

Comment: How do you restart the database?

Comment: closing runManagerSwing.bat or closing my application, which contains the shutdown in the connection url, so I don't know if it deletes db.properties or if it just removes the property I added

Comment: The best way to check if the file still exists after that is to check the file. But this should not be the case. I could not find out if the properties are deleted. Maybe the log file could help.

Comment: Actually the properties file should be there.

Comment: The properties that are not persisted in the database do not have an SQL equivalent (e.g. `hsqldb.full_log_replay`). Some other properties have an effect only on the connection that creates the database.